# Select last non-NA column of a list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

I am currently trying to parse RDP multiclassifier hierarchy files in R, however the problem is more generally applicable. Basically I create a list which contains data-frames of several files which contain "hierarchical" rows:

```
dput(corner(hierlist$hier_M2MID06_Trimmed_noGaps.fas_fixrank.txt,n=c(7,10)))
structure(list(X1 = structure(c(30L, 31L, 163L, 45L, 64L, 65L, 
66L), .Label = c("-1071", "-1102", "-1153", "-1159", "-1176", 
"-1177", "-1207", "-1241", "-1256", "-1281", "-1332", "-1353", 
"-1354", "-1502", "-1567", "-18", "-2", "-2715", "-423", "-460", 
"-463", "-471", "-567", "-568", "-828", "-842", "-843", "-871", 
"-980", "0", "1", "1031", "1069", "1070", "1093", "1101", "1126", 
"1151", "1152", "1158", "1159", "1164", "1165", "1166", "1175", 
"1176", "1195", "1200", "1206", "1207", "1215", "1216", "1217", 
"1219", "1240", "1251", "1255", "1256", "1261", "1269", "1279", 
"1280", "1282", "1330", "1331", "1339", "1341", "1343", "1348", 
"1352", "1353", "1354", "1355", "1356", "1357", "1358", "1360", 
"1501", "1566", "16", "1668", "1672", "1674", "17", "1762", "1763", 
"1764", "1767", "1883", "1884", "1885", "1891", "1893", "1894", 
"2", "2164", "2179", "2180", "2183", "2184", "2187", "2192", 
"2195", "2208", "2209", "2210", "2211", "2259", "2260", "2333", 
"2371", "2372", "254", "255", "261", "264", "2684", "2713", "2714", 
"274", "3", "35", "422", "458", "459", "46", "462", "470", "48", 
"49", "54", "565", "566", "567", "570", "577", "581", "648", 
"653", "657", "659", "804", "805", "806", "807", "808", "817", 
"818", "819", "820", "822", "824", "825", "826", "827", "829", 
"832", "834", "837", "838", "839", "840", "841", "842", "843", 
"844", "846", "848", "870", "886", "887", "908", "918", "927", 
"929", "950", "957", "978", "979", "taxid"), class = "factor"), 
X2 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Root", 
"lineage", "null"), class = "factor"), X3 = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Root", "name", "rootrank"
), class = "factor"), X4 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("Bacteria", "no rank", "rank"), class = "factor"), 
X5 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("194", 
"M2MID06_Trimmed_noGaps.fas", "domain"), class = "factor"), 
X6 = structure(c(NA, NA, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("", 
"Acidobacteria", "Actinobacteria", "Bacteroidetes", "Cyanobacteria/Chloroplast", 
"Firmicutes", "Gemmatimonadetes", "Nitrospira", "Planctomycetes", 
"Proteobacteria", "Spirochaetes", "Verrucomicrobia", "unclassified_Bacteria"
), class = "factor"), X7 = structure(c(NA, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), .Label = c("", "Bacteria", "phylum"), class = "factor"), 
X8 = structure(c(NA, 21L, NA, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), .Label = c("", 
"Acidobacteria_Gp3", "Acidobacteria_Gp4", "Actinobacteria", 
"Alphaproteobacteria", "Bacilli", "Bacteroidetes_incertae_sedis", 
"Betaproteobacteria", "Chloroplast", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Flavobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", "Gemmatimonadetes", 
"Nitrospira", "Phycisphaerae", "Planctomycetacia", "Sphingobacteria", 
"Spirochaetes", "Subdivision3", "Verrucomicrobiae", "domain", 
"unclassified_Bacteroidetes", "unclassified_Proteobacteria"
), class = "factor"), X9 = structure(c(NA, 2L, 11L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L), .Label = c("", "194", "Acidobacteria", "Actinobacteria", 
"Bacteroidetes", "Cyanobacteria/Chloroplast", "Firmicutes", 
"Gemmatimonadetes", "Nitrospira", "Planctomycetes", "Proteobacteria", 
"Spirochaetes", "Verrucomicrobia", "class", "unclassified_Bacteria"
), class = "factor"), X10 = structure(c(NA, NA, 29L, NA, 
22L, 22L, 22L), .Label = c("", "Actinobacteridae", "Bdellovibrionales", 
"Burkholderiales", "Caulobacterales", "Chloroplast", "Chromatiales", 
"Flavobacteriales", "Gemmatimonadales", "Gp3", "Gp4", "Lactobacillales", 
"Legionellales", "Methylophilales", "Nitrospirales", "Ohtaekwangia", 
"Phycisphaerales", "Planctomycetales", "Pseudomonadales", 
"Rhizobiales", "Rhodobacterales", "Rhodocyclales", "Rhodospirillales", 
"Sphingobacteriales", "Sphingomonadales", "Spirochaetales", 
"Subdivision3_genera_incertae_sedis", "Verrucomicrobiales", 
"phylum", "unclassified_Alphaproteobacteria", "unclassified_Betaproteobacteria", 
"unclassified_Deltaproteobacteria", "unclassified_Gammaproteobacteria"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", 
"X5", "X6", "X7", "X8", "X9", "X10"), row.names = 2:8, class = "data.frame")
```

This basically means I have progressive rows which are filled up with NA in progressive columns. However, there is no way of telling of a specific row where the first `NA` will be. Preceding this first `NA` column, I have the two columns which actually interest me: a count of the number of contigs at a specified taxonomical level, and two columns before it the taxonomic level's name.

I already created a list containing the indices for each dataframe that would select the last row by:

```
library(plyr)
lastcollist<-lapply(hierlist,function(p)lapply(apply(p, 1, function(x) which(!is.na(x)) ),function(x)if(length(x)>0){max(x)}else{0}))
lastcollist<-lapply(lastcollist,unlist)
lastcollist.idx<-llply(lastcollist,function(x)cbind(seq(1,length(x)),x))
```

Here `lastcollist.idx` will contain the indices of each row with the last non-`NA` column:

```
head(lastcollist.idx$hier_M2MID06_Trimmed_noGaps.fas_fixrank.txt)
        x
[1,] 1  5
[2,] 2  5
[3,] 3  9
[4,] 4 11
[5,] 5 13
[6,] 6 15
```

So what I would basically want to do now is create a new list which contains dataframes (or in the case of only the last column, variable `x` in `lastcollist.idx`) that have for each given row the last selected column.

This would be the desired output for the given example:

```
 dput(rbind(c('domain','194'),c('Proteobacteria','Phylum'),c('Betaproteobacteria','class'),c ('class','Rhodocyclales'),c('class','Rhodocyclales'),c('class','Rhodocyclales')))
structure(c("domain", "Proteobacteria", "Betaproteobacteria", 
"class", "class", "class", "194", "Phylum", "class", "Rhodocyclales", 
"Rhodocyclales", "Rhodocyclales"), .Dim = c(6L, 2L))
```

And I have to admit, I wouldn't immediately know how to do so. Any pointers are warmly welcomed. I am not a novice to R, so you don't have to go through great lengths in your explanation.

For a larger reproducible example consider the dataset 'khanmiss' from the bioconductor library impute ([bioconductor library impute](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/impute.html)).

```
 source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
 biocLite("impute")
 require(impute)
 data(khanmiss)
```

Which is basically a dataframe that has NAs introduced in several places. It is not exactly the same hierarchical structure as my file but it will fit the purpose. As this is a very inconvenient dataframe with 2309 observations and only 222 of it's rows contain missing values, I selected the rows with missing values and added 78 rows randomly that did not have missing values in a new data.frame. This data.frame was then split into a list of 4 dataframes of arbirtraty size (adding up to 300).

```
isnadf<-as.data.frame(which(is.na(khanmiss),arr.ind=T))
na.rows<-sort(unique(isnadf$row))
length(na.rows) #the dataset has 222 rows which contain NA
na.khanmiss<-khanmiss[na.rows,]
notna.rows<-setdiff(rownames(khanmiss),na.rows)
notna.rows.selected<-sort(as.numeric(sample(notna.rows,78)))
notna.selected.khanmiss<-khanmiss[notna.rows.selected,]
khanmiss.selected<-rbind(na.khanmiss,notna.selected.khanmiss)
dfsizes<-c(82,74,79,65) #arbitrarily selected, adds up to 300
khanmiss.list<-split(khanmiss.selected,rep(letters[1:4],dfsizes))
```

Which finally gives a list somewhat similar to my dataset.

Comment: Should we know about *RDP multiclassifier hierarchy files* to be able to help? If not, I have to admit it is quite hard to follow. Can you dumb it down to something small (e.g., why tell us you have a list of data.frames and not just one data.frame?) and easy to understand, with an example for the input and the expected output.

Comment: Nevertheless, I'll point you to matrix indexing as a possible solution. See for example what this does: `m <- matrix(1:12, 3, 4); m[cbind(c(1:3), c(3,2,4))]`

Comment: Hi @flodel, it is a more general question but the input list is quite difficult to generate generically. A dput structure would be enormous (it is a 2 Mb list). I will try to reformulate my question: I have a list of dataframes because I read multiple (30 some) files using read.table. Each file forms a new data.frame in the list. Manually making each dataframe is quite laborious and furthermore these files are read by grepping certain files from a directory so the amount of files can change. (...)

Comment: (...) ctd the issue then is that for every dataframe I need the value of last column of each row which does not contain 'NA', and the value on the same row two columns before that. The index of this last column can change each row. Finally my output should be a list containing data.frames with two columns. Thanks for the tip on the matrix indexing, but I would rather not have to convert back and forth from df to matrix for the operation.

Comment: Well, the ideal would have been you create a data.frame by hand with say, six columns and five rows, with NA's in appropriate places to handle all cases. And the expected output that goes with it. Your `corner(hierlist$hier_M2MID06_Trimmed_noGaps.fas_fixrank.txt,n=c(7,10))` isn't too bad of an example, you could have just given the `dput` of that all called it your data. Also when I say the expected output, I mean the exact data structure along with the explanation.

Comment: You make a fair point @flodel, I guess I overcomplicated the question by trying to supply a good dataset. Also the lack of desired output format is a problem here.I will edit my question accordingly. I have also supplied below with a dput structure that is a tad larger.

Comment: Argggh. Still no reproducible data. the object `hierlist` is never established.

Comment: @IShouldBuyABoat: I beg to differ. I went through a great deal of work to supply the structure of the individual data.frames in the list both from the input as from the desired output side. Furthermore, I went on the look for a dataset that was big enough to simulate my data. However, as this is still not considered as reproducible data you can find "hierlist.RData" at: http://bit.ly/LXD9Tx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something along these untested lines might work:

```
apply(dfrm, 1, function(r) { r[ (which(is.na(r))[1]-1):(which(is.na(r))[1]-2)) ] } )
```

My usual ways of load text output as dataframes are failing for this example so my suggestion is to post `dput` output rather than screen scrapings. (It also appears to me that you should have done your data entry with header =TRUE since your first row of data does not look like data.)

With the new data (and realizing the need to test for no NA's:

```
 apply(hierlist, 1, function(r) { r[ 
                      if( any(is.na(r))){ 
                          (which(is.na(r))[1]-1):( which(is.na(r))[1]-2) 
                       }else{
                          (length(r)-2): (length(r)-1)}
                                      ] }
       )
#--------------------------------------
     2         3          4                5                   
[1,] "194"     "domain"   "phylum"         "class"             
[2,] "no rank" "Bacteria" "Proteobacteria" "Betaproteobacteria"
     6                    7                    8                   
[1,] "Betaproteobacteria" "Betaproteobacteria" "Betaproteobacteria"
[2,] "class"              "class"              "class"
```

> 

Comment: Hi @IShouldBuyABoat, the reason I did not load with header=T is because of the variable number of columns in the source file. I am aware that the first row is "header like" but actually I am not intersted in this row. I just grepped my fileslist with some pattern: `filen<-grep("^h.*noGaps.fas_fixrank.txt",list.files(),value=T)` then I loaded each file in the list `hierlist<-list()` `for(i in filen){no.col<-max(count.fields(i,sep=";"));hierlist[[i]]<-read.table(i,header=F,sep=";",fill=T,col.names=1:no.col)}` without `header=F` this would result in an error.

Comment: I tried to make a dput of the list but it is just too big (2Mb). Even trying to dput just 2 elements of the list is impossible as the R console doesn't give a long enough output, and I wouldn't be able to post in on SO either way. On http://bit.ly/1hFfNwh you will find a link to a dput of the first dataframe of the list. The other dataframes have a comparable structure.

Comment: `dput(head(dfrm, 30))`

Comment: As you can see in the edit I did to the question and my discussion with flodel above I provide now a dput of the corner of the dataframe (corner is a function from package BurStMisc, which basically is a 2 d head function).