# split dataframe in groups before each non-NA

Tags: r, split, subset, apply, na

1. I am looking to split my dataframe into subsets according to the column "Height" with each subset having one row with a value and 0-Inf rows with NAs.
2. This is, to be able to apply functions to the subsets afterwards, specifically order the rows according to their "Diameter" value, number of rows in each subset, sqrt(sum(Diameter^2)) etc.

1.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
> dput(df[1:300, c("IDD", "Height", "Diameter")])
structure(list(IDD = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 
45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 
61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 
77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 
93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 
107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 
120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 
133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 
146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 
159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 
172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 
185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 
198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 
211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 
224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 
237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 
250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 
263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 
276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 
289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300), 
    Height = c(6.7, 4.7, 2.2, NA, 1.3, NA, 1.15, 2.2, 2.5, NA, 
    5.25, NA, 1.8, 3.7, 1.3, 1.85, 2.2, NA, NA, 1.7, 2.6, 2.4, 
    NA, NA, 4.3, 2.25, NA, NA, NA, 5.1, 2.8, NA, 4, 5.8, 6.2, 
    NA, NA, NA, 5.8, 5.2, 2.45, NA, 1.25, 1.3, NA, 1.7, NA, NA, 
    4.4, 1.9, 4.4, NA, NA, NA, 8.5, 1.2, NA, 3.1, NA, 1.1, 1.1, 
    3.7, 5.5, NA, NA, 7.5, 2.4, 1.2, NA, 2.1, NA, 1.3, NA, NA, 
    1.2, 1.8, 6.2, NA, NA, NA, 1.5, 1.9, 1.15, 2.6, NA, 2.8, 
    1.7, 2.4, NA, NA, 5.2, 2.6, 1.3, 2.25, NA, 1.8, NA, 2, NA, 
    2.15, 1.9, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.2, NA, 7.6, NA, 1.4, 
    NA, 2.8, 1.15, 4, 2.1, NA, NA, 4.2, 1.1, 4.7, 2.5, NA, 6.2, 
    2.4, 3.8, 2.2, 2.8, 7.8, 2.4, 1.3, 2.2, 3.2, 4.2, 3, NA, 
    NA, 3.7, 2.6, NA, 1.8, NA, NA, 2.3, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5.6, 
    2.3, 1.8, 3.6, NA, NA, NA, 1.7, NA, 4.2, 3.1, NA, NA, 3, 
    6, NA, 2.4, NA, NA, NA, 4.4, NA, 4.1, 2.3, 6.2, 2.4, NA, 
    NA, 3, 2.4, NA, 4.3, NA, NA, NA, 5.7, 1.6, NA, NA, 2.6, NA, 
    NA, 2.3, NA, NA, NA, 2, 1.5, NA, 1.15, NA, NA, 1.8, 2.6, 
    1.6, 2.25, 1.25, NA, 1.3, NA, 1.15, 1.1, 1.2, 2.2, NA, 1.35, 
    NA, 1.1, 1.4, NA, NA, 3.7, 1.9, 7.1, 2.15, 1.8, 2.7, 6.8, 
    NA, NA, NA, 2.05, 1.9, 3.4, 3.4, 1.7, 1.7, 1.5, 1.3, 2.5, 
    1.05, 1.05, NA, 1.1, 1.1, 1.5, 1.55, 1.25, 1.1, 1, NA, 2.1, 
    4.4, 1.8, 1.4, NA, 2.6, 1.1, NA, 1.75, NA, NA, 1.2, NA, 2.7, 
    NA, 4.6, NA, NA, 3.9, NA, NA, 4.3, 1.6, NA, 1.5, NA, 3.9, 
    3.2, 2.6, NA, 4.6, 2.65, NA, 1.75, NA, 1.2, 2.15, 1.65, NA, 
    NA, 2.25, 1.1, 1.55, 1.35, NA, 1.2, 2.5, 1.2, 6.1, 1.8), 
    Diameter = c(7.480282325, 4.774648293, 2.387324146, 1.432394488, 
    1.909859317, 1.909859317, 1.273239545, 1.909859317, 1.750704374, 
    1.750704374, 4.13802852, 1.591549431, 2.228169203, 3.660563691, 
    1.432394488, 2.06901426, 2.387324146, 0.795774715, 13.52817016, 
    1.432394488, 2.06901426, 2.387324146, 1.432394488, 1.273239545, 
    3.501408748, 2.387324146, 2.06901426, 1.432394488, 1.273239545, 
    3.501408748, 2.228169203, 1.750704374, 2.864788976, 4.13802852, 
    6.047887837, 4.456338407, 2.546479089, 1.591549431, 3.978873577, 
    3.660563691, 2.387324146, 1.750704374, 2.06901426, 1.432394488, 
    1.750704374, 1.750704374, 1.273239545, 1.273239545, 3.183098862, 
    1.909859317, 3.660563691, 1.909859317, 1.273239545, 1.114084602, 
    8.116902098, 1.591549431, 1.432394488, 2.228169203, 1.909859317, 
    1.432394488, 1.432394488, 3.342253805, 3.342253805, 3.183098862, 
    3.342253805, 5.092958179, 2.06901426, 1.432394488, 1.432394488, 
    1.750704374, 1.273239545, 1.591549431, 1.114084602, 22.75915686, 
    1.750704374, 3.023943919, 5.729577951, 2.705634033, 17.66619868, 
    10.50422624, 1.432394488, 2.228169203, 1.114084602, 1.909859317, 
    1.750704374, 2.864788976, 1.591549431, 2.228169203, 0.954929659, 
    1.114084602, 4.774648293, 1.909859317, 1.114084602, 2.387324146, 
    2.037183272, 1.591549431, 1.432394488, 1.591549431, 1.273239545, 
    2.228169203, 1.909859317, 1.273239545, 1.273239545, 1.591549431, 
    1.273239545, 1.273239545, 0.954929659, 2.546479089, 3.023943919, 
    13.05070533, 5.570423008, 1.591549431, 1.273239545, 2.546479089, 
    1.591549431, 3.023943919, 2.06901426, 1.432394488, 10.3450713, 
    3.342253805, 1.750704374, 5.092958179, 2.705634033, 2.228169203, 
    7.161972439, 1.782535363, 3.023943919, 1.909859317, 1.432394488, 
    6.525352667, 2.387324146, 1.273239545, 1.909859317, 2.06901426, 
    3.501408748, 2.705634033, 1.273239545, 1.273239545, 3.501408748, 
    1.909859317, 1.432394488, 1.909859317, 1.114084602, 1.432394488, 
    2.06901426, 12.5732405, 1.432394488, 21.8042272, 24.19155135, 
    6.843662553, 2.228169203, 2.06901426, 3.342253805, 1.909859317, 
    1.432394488, 2.06901426, 2.228169203, 1.750704374, 3.342253805, 
    2.864788976, 1.273239545, 1.750704374, 2.705634033, 5.729577951, 
    2.06901426, 2.705634033, 1.750704374, 1.591549431, 1.591549431, 
    2.864788976, 1.114084602, 2.705634033, 2.228169203, 5.252113122, 
    2.546479089, 0.954929659, 1.591549431, 2.06901426, 2.228169203, 
    1.273239545, 3.501408748, 0.795774715, 1.273239545, 1.273239545, 
    5.252113122, 1.591549431, 1.432394488, 1.432394488, 2.705634033, 
    1.432394488, 1.591549431, 2.546479089, 1.273239545, 1.432394488, 
    1.432394488, 2.06901426, 1.591549431, 1.432394488, 1.750704374, 
    1.273239545, 1.273239545, 1.909859317, 2.546479089, 0.954929659, 
    2.705634033, 2.06901426, 0.954929659, 1.114084602, 1.273239545, 
    1.273239545, 1.273239545, 1.273239545, 1.909859317, 1.432394488, 
    1.273239545, 1.273239545, 1.909859317, 1.750704374, 5.252113122, 
    1.273239545, 3.501408748, 2.546479089, 7.161972439, 2.228169203, 
    1.909859317, 2.387324146, 4.456338407, 1.591549431, 3.501408748, 
    1.273239545, 1.750704374, 1.909859317, 2.705634033, 3.342253805, 
    1.909859317, 1.750704374, 2.06901426, 2.228169203, 2.546479089, 
    1.273239545, 1.750704374, 0.954929659, 1.591549431, 1.591549431, 
    2.06901426, 1.750704374, 1.591549431, 1.273239545, 1.273239545, 
    1.432394488, 1.909859317, 3.660563691, 2.228169203, 1.750704374, 
    1.273239545, 2.546479089, 2.864788976, 1.114084602, 1.273239545, 
    1.432394488, 1.273239545, 1.750704374, 1.273239545, 2.705634033, 
    0.954929659, 3.501408748, 1.750704374, 1.591549431, 3.023943919, 
    1.909859317, 1.591549431, 3.183098862, 1.750704374, 0.795774715, 
    1.591549431, 1.432394488, 3.501408748, 2.546479089, 2.864788976, 
    2.546479089, 4.13802852, 2.705634033, 2.546479089, 2.387324146, 
    1.591549431, 1.273239545, 2.705634033, 2.387324146, 1.273239545, 
    1.114084602, 2.705634033, 1.591549431, 1.591549431, 1.432394488, 
    1.273239545, 1.591549431, 2.387324146, 1.432394488, 4.933803236, 
    1.909859317)), .Names = c("IDD", "Height", "Diameter"), row.names = c(NA, 
300L), class = "data.frame")
```

and inspired by the answer to this question [Select last non-NA column of a list of dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21223965/select-last-non-na-column-of-a-list-of-dataframes)
I tried to create the following function

```
ind <- apply(df["Height"], 1, function(r) {
     r[ (which(!is.na(r))[1]) : (which(!is.na(r))[2]+1) ] } )
```

which however gives me the error
`error in (which(!is.na(r))[1]):(which(!is.na(r))[2] + 1) : 
  NA/NaN Argument`

So I tried the same with tapply and it errors `undefined columns selected` - but df["Height"] is a defined column, or am I wrong? I used tapply because I thought it might be a dataframe/vector class issue.

2.

I'm not sure about how to apply the functions when I have the subset. 
Specifically I have no clue for ordering the rows of each subset acc. to `desc(Diameter)`.
For the stem no. and the average Diameter, this should work right?

```
ddply(ind, .(ID, class), summarise,
    stems = length(ID),
    avg_diameter = sqrt(sum((Diameter)^2)))
```

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think

```
library("plyr")
df <- mutate(df,ID=cumsum(!is.na(df$Height)))
dfsum <- ddply(df,.(ID),summarise,
           stems=length(ID),
           avg_diameter = sqrt(sum((Diameter)^2)))
head(dfsum)
##   ID stems avg_diameter
## 1  1     1     7.480282
## 2  2     1     4.774648
```

should work ... ?

To "order[] the rows of each subset acc. to desc(Diameter)",

```
ddply(df,.(ID), arrange,desc(Diameter))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ben, worked perfectly! `cumsum` seems a really useful function which I haven't understood yet...
The ordering also worked, I only added the `desc()` : `ddply(df,.(ID), arrange, desc(Diameter))`